# problems writing code for a JavaScript coin toss game

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm struggling to get the hang of JavaScript and am practicing by trying to write a coin toss game using conditional statements and functions can someone point out where I'm going wrong?

```
var coinToss = prompt("heads or tails?");
console.log(coinToss);
var headTails = function() {
    var outCome = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
    if (outCome === 1) {
        outCome = "heads";
    } else {
        outCome = "tails";
    }
};
console.log(outCome);


var compare = function(outCome, coinToss) {
    if (outCome === coinToss.toLowerCase) {
        document.write("<p>You Win!</p>");
    }  else {
        document.write("<p>You Loss!</p>")
    };
};
```

Comment: You didn't call `headTails` function. Besides `outCome` is private in `headTails` scope then you should return it as the result of function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `toLowerCase` is a method hence `toLowerCase()`
- Call the function as `compare(headTails(), coinToss);`
- Return the value from function `headTails`
- Ternary could be used instead of `if-else`

```js
var coinToss = prompt("heads or tails?");
var headTails = function() {
  var outCome = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1;
  console.log(outCome === 1 ? "heads" : "tails");
  return outCome === 1 ? "heads" : "tails";
};

var compare = function(outCome, coinToss) {
  if (outCome === coinToss.toLowerCase()) {
    document.write("<p>You Win!</p>");
  } else {
    document.write("<p>You Loss!</p>")
  };
};
compare(headTails(), coinToss);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the compare function, like so:

```
compare(headsTails(),coinToss);
```